# Cassandra client connection to multiple addresses

Tags: cassandra

I have a question about Cassandra.
Is it possible to open Cassandra client connection on many IPs?

On my server I have 2 network cards (eth0 and eth1) with IP 10.197.11.21 (eth0) and 192.168.0.45 (eth1) and 127.0.0.1 (lo).

I want my client to connect to Cassandra database with this three IP
in localhost, 10.197.11.21 and 192.168.0.45

For the moment I can choose only 1 IP, what does it do to modify in the file cassandra.yaml ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configMultiNetworks.html

Comment: yes, i modify ma yaml file and add :
listen_address: 10.197.11.21 127.0.0.1
broadcast_address: 10.197.11.255 127.0.0.1
listen_on_broadcast_address: true
seeds: "10.197.11.21, 127.0.0.1"
but it's not work when i try to connect in localhost

Comment: you can use 0.0.0.0 in Cassandra.yaml  listen_on__address to see the Cassandra on all interfaces.

Comment: listen_on__address parameter not exist in cassandra.yaml
for parameter listen_address, i can not set 0.0.0.0 because in cassandra doc : setting listen_address to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `rpc_address: 0.0.0.0` in [cassandra.yaml](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html)

Note that when you set `rpc_address` to 0.0.0.0, you also **must** set `broadcast_rpc_address` to something other than 0.0.0.0 (e.g. 10.197.11.21).

- [rpc_address](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#rpc-address) is the address that Cassandra listens on for connections from clients
- [listen_address](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#listen-address) is the address that Cassandra listens on for connections from other Cassandra nodes (*not* client connections)
- [broadcast_rpc_address](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#broadcast-rpc-address) is the address that Cassandra broadcasts to clients that are attempting to discover the other nodes in the cluster. When an application first connects to a Cassandra cluster, the cluster sends the application a list of all the nodes in the cluster, and their IP addresses. The IP address sent to the application is the `broadcast_ip_address` (side-note: cassandra actually sends all IP addresses, this is just the one that it tells the client to connect on). This allows the application to auto-discover all the nodes in the cluster, even if only one IP address was given to the application. This also allows applications to handle situations like a node going offline, or new nodes being added.

Even though your `broadcast_rpc_address` can only point to one of those two IP addresses, you application can still connect to either one. However, your application will also attempt to connect to other nodes via the `broadcast_rpc_address`es sent back by the cluster. You can get around this by providing a full list of the address of every node in the cluster to your application, but the best solution is to build a [driver-side address translator](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/address_resolution/#driver-side-address-translation).